# How to convert hash values into appropriate data types for SQL queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

The problem I am having is the values in a hash may not be the right data type in order to be successful in a where clause (as one example).

For example, there are filter parameters that may be passed on the URL: some may be strings, some numbers, some boolean. The final hash would be something like filter_parms: {id: "1", active: "true", name: "John"} and so on. The problem should be obvious: everything is treated as a string. I am trying to find a way to automatically coerce the values into becoming the correct data types (e.g. "1" => 1, "true" => true) in a nice, elegant way without looping through and creating a coding mess.

The end goal is to be able to use the hash in something like this: Person.where(filter_parms). This works fine for the String fields, but not for boolean and int.

I have tried using sanitize_sql_for_conditions, but its output matches the input data types exactly without making any modifications.

I imagine there is something obvious that I am missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do things to normalize your data like this:

```
def normalize(value)
  case (value)
  when 'true'
    true
  when 'false'
    false
  when 'null','nil'
    nil
  when /\A-?\d+\z/
    value.to_i
  when /\A-?\d+\.\d+\z/
    value.to_f
  else
    value
  end
end
```

There's risks here in interpreting the values incorrectly, like if a field could contain the string literal `"true"` and you want that preserved this will mangle it, and likewise, phone numbers of the form `8889991111` will be coerced into numbers that might not fit in 32-bit forms, so that could be a problem for some systems.

The reason there's no automatic way is because converting it like this isn't hard, plus a lot of the conversion is highly contextual.

Comment: You could look at `Model.columns` and their `#sql_type`s to make things less error prone.

Comment: I was definitely kind of hoping there was a way to drive the values through some kind of sanitizer that was driven by the model. Not sure how Rails handles this on posted form data. I assume there is something in the post that explicitly declares the data types of each parm.

Comment: @muistooshort - I will checkout the Model.columns if only to at least be consistent and thorough...

Comment: Rails is fairly lenient about the sorts of data you can accept, though it's also driven by tradition. `0` or `1` for `boolean` type columns, automatic conversion of integer or date types, that sort of thing. I'd evaluate if you actually need this, or if your form can be adjusted to better fit ActiveRecord's expectations.